# NXT light sensor homework help

Tags: nxt, programming, robotic, labview

- Read value from NXT kit using light sensor and show it in the middle of NXT screen.
- If measured lightness value is less than or equal to 50, right motor will stop and left motor will move with the power of 35.
- If measured lightness value is greater than 50, left motor will stop and right motor will move with the power of 35.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Without solving your homework, you will need at least the following blocks:

for bullet 1

- Light Sensor
- Data to Text
- LCD Panel Display

for bullets 2 and 3

- Loop (forever)
- Switch (based on light sensor readings)
- Motor Block (4 of these, 2 for > 50% + 2 for <= 50%)

And it probably makes sense to put bullet 1 inside the loop of bullets 2 and 3.